# No route matches [GET] with query string in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails and I'm having issues setting up non-resourceful routes with querystring parameters. I am trying to access the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/exerciseLogs?userID=1
```

When I access this URL, I receive the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/exerciseLogs"
```

My routes file is defined as follows:

```
get 'exerciseLogs?userID=:user_id' => 'exercise_logs#index', :defaults => { :format => 'json'},  :as => :get_user_exercise_logs
get 'exerciseLogs/:id' => 'exercise_logs#show', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }, :as => :get_exercise_log
post 'exerciseLogs?userID=:user_id' => "exercise_logs#create", :defaults => { :format => 'json'}, :as => :create_exercise_log
patch 'exerciseLogs/:id' => 'exercise_logs#update', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }, :as => :update_exercise_log_patch
put 'exerciseLogs/:id' => 'exercise_logs#update', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }, :as => :update_exercise_log_put
delete 'exerciseLogs/:id' => 'exercise_logs#destroy', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }, :as => :delete_exercise_log
```

What is the best way to solve this problem so that my routes actually go the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to define query string parameters in your route. For details checkout [`rails routes with query string`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string). So in your case you can do something like this:

```
get '/exerciseLogs' => 'exercise_logs#index', :defaults => { :format => 'json'},  :as => :get_user_exercise_logs
```

Answer (score -1):

Define route like this

```
get 'exerciseLogs/user/:user_id' => 'exercise_logs#user_log_index', :defaults => { :format => 'json'},  :as => :get_user_exercise_logs
```

and then access it

```
http://localhost:3000/exerciseLogs/user/1
```

Define seperate action user_log_index in controller

Comment: Unfortunately your solution does not meet my requirements as I am looking for a URL like the following:

   http://localhost:3000/exerciseLogs?user_id=user_id

The URL you have provided would get a single log rather than the logs for an entire user.

Comment: Please elaborate, what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I'd like to have a URL that allows me to retrieve the logs for a single user.